# Apache mod_rewrite query strings

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

So my `staff.php?action=[action]` file is rewritten to `/staff/[action]` where `action` can take 3 values `new/edit/delete`.

I want to display success or failure messages on submission. I tried to redirect to `/staff/new&error=[error]` or `/staff/new?error=[error]`.

However, the `var_dump($_GET)` only returns the `action`'s query string.

The only solution I found is `/staff?action=[action]&error=[error]`, but I don't like it. Is there any way of rewriting my rules?

I don't want `/staff/new/error/[error]`

```
## hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^staff/(.+)$ /staff.php?action=$1 [L]
```

Comment: add your rewrite rule, you are probably missing [QSA] , but it's just a guess since there's no code.

Comment: I want many things, yet you do **not** want to show us your rewrite rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **QSA** flag to add query string to your forwarded page

```
RewriteRule ^staff/(new|edit|delete)$ /staff.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Alright, but what if somebody types `/staff/new&a=b`? I will get a `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: Why would you ? It would be forwarded to `/staff.php?action=new&a=b`. Anyway you should always check your GET parameters for security reasons. Is there only `error` parameter that could be added to your query string in this case ? If yes, then a condition can be added to match only that possibility